# Eloquent query based on calculation of two columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model called `quotation` which has both a `created_at` and a `valid_for` column.

How can a run one eloquent query so that it returns expired quotations (without manually adding a `expired_at` column e.g. something like this

```
$quotations = Quotation::where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->addDays($this->valid_for));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the logic in the sql.

```
$quotations = Quotation::where(\DB::row('DATE_ADD(`created_at`, INTERVAL `valid_for` DAY)', '>=', \DB::row('CURRENT_DATE'))->get();
```

I assume your `valid_for` is number of days.

Comment: Can I do this with eloquent?

Comment: This is using Eloquent only.

Comment: Sorry I meant using without DB queries? Also, this is giving an error "does not have a method 'row'"